# What does this prime symbol do - MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I am working with some matlab code I inhereted from another person, I dont understand the meaning of the line q =[q; qi']. I feel like i should be able to just remove it, so that q = distribuc...

```
function [ q ] = ObtainHistogramForEachTarget( state, numberOfTargets, image, q )

    for i=1 : numberOfTargets
        qi = distribucion_color_bin_RGB2(state(i).xPosition,state(i).yPosition,state(i).size,image,2);
        q = [q; qi'];
    end
end
```

Can anyone explain this to me?

Comment: I think from memory it represents a transposition to a matrix, i would need to check.

Comment: I would replace `'` with `.'` because the first is a complex conjugate transpose and the latter just a regular transpose.

Comment: @ja72 If you never work with complex numbers a simple `'` should be enough. As the asker loops over `i` it should be safe to keep things simple.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin unless the conjugate transpose is intended to be used, it is recommended to always use the regular transpose, with symbol `.'`.

Comment: @ja72 Do you have a reference for that? On the mathworks site I always just see the regular `'` being used when working with real numbers so I assume that is good practice. http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/learn_matlab/matrices-and-magic-squares.html?s_tid=doc_12b

Answer (score 7, accepted):

MATLAB has several built-in functions to manipulate matrices. The special character, `'`, for prime denotes the transpose of a matrix.

The statement `A = [ 1 2 3;4 5 6;7 8 9]'` produces the matrix

```
A = 
   1 4 7 
   2 5 8
   3 6 9
```

hope this helps

Comment: Note that `.'` is transpose and `'` is complex conjugate transpose. The difference is very important when working with complex data.

Answer (score 5):

From Matlab's help

> help ctranspose
>    '   Complex conjugate transpose.
>        X' is the complex conjugate transpose of X.
>
> ```
>  B = ctranspose(A) is called for the syntax A' (complex conjugate
>  transpose) when A is an object.
> ```

Answer (score 4):

The `[X ; Y]` syntax concatenates two matrices vertically.  So that line is adding the just-computed results to the already computed `q`.  If you simply reassigned `q`, you would be discarding all the computations the function had already done each time through the loop.

The forward apostrophe `'` does a complex conjugate and transposes a matrix.  I would guess that `distribucion_color_bin_RGB2` probably returns a real-valued column vector, and the author wanted to flip it to horizontal before appending it to the results matrix.

As @ja72 pointed out, it's better style to use `.'` (just transpose) by default and `'` only when you actually mean a complex conjugate, even if you expect your data to be real.

Answer (score 0):

usually A' is the transpose of matrix A, but it is conjugate transpose. it works for real matrix, doesn't work for complex matrix

transpose(A) is the real transpose function, both work for R matrix and C matrix.

I usually use A', it's easy, but I changed my habit until I face bug in FFT transformation

Answer (score 0):

I came across the same problem and tested it using octave(matlab in ubuntu), and found that to a just complex number `a`, `a'` means its conjugate.

```
octave:2> a = 1 + 1j
a =  1 + 1i
octave:3> a'
ans =  1 - 1i
```

Besides, to a complex matrix `A`:

```
octave:6> A = [1 + 2j 1 - 2j ; 2 - 1j 2 + 1j]
A =

   1 + 2i   1 - 2i
   2 - 1i   2 + 1i

octave:7> A'
ans =

   1 - 2i   2 + 1i
   1 + 2i   2 - 1i
```